# TypeError for string to integer

Tags: python

I am writing a function for conversion of array.
What I am doing is that I want string to be converted to integer but not on the indices where it contain '+' , '-' , '*' and '/'.
The function is given below

```
def Str_to_int(arr):
    arr1 = [len(arr)]
    arr2 = [len(arr)]
    for i in arr:
        if arr[i] != '+' or arr[i] != '-' or arr[i] != '*' or arr[i] != '/':
            arr2[i] = arr[i]
        else:
            arr1[i] = arr[i]
    return arr2
```

I call this function like

```
var1 = input("Enter String  \n")
var2 = Str_to_int(var1)
print(var2)
```

But it is giving me an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
var2 = Str_to_int(var1)
if arr[i] != '+' or arr[i] != '-' or arr[i] != '*' or arr[i] != '/':
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Can someone please tell me how do I correct it?

Comment: I think you need to use `and` not `or`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating over the *elements* of the list, not its indices; that is, `i` is what you think `arr[i]` should be. As you actually need the indices, you could iterate over them explicitly:

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
```

although a more Pythonic idiom is to use the `enumerate` function instead, which gives you an element of the list *and* its index at the same time.

```
for i, x in enumerate(arr):
    if x not in '+-*/':
        arr2[i] = x
    else:
        arr1[i] = x
```

Comment: for both it is giving me an error                               IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: That's because I didn't duplicate the original initalization of `arr1` or `arr2` (which wasn't correct anyway). You probably meant `arr1 = list(range(arr))` (or an equivalent), or you can simply append with `arr1.append(x)` (having initialized `arr1 = []` prior to the loop), depending on what `arr1` or `arr2` actually need to be.

Comment: arr1 is for integer and arr2 is for storing + - * /

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're using `for i in arr` to iterate over a string.  When iterating over a string like this, `i` is the *characters* in the string, not a numeric value.  That's why you can't access `arr[i]`.

Comment: How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you want to enumerate the list.  With `for i in arr` you're iterating through the characters in the string `arr` then trying to use those to index.  So for example if `arr` is "String" then:

```
for i in arr:
    print i

S
t
r
i
n 
g

for i, ch in enumerate(arr):
   print i, ch

0, S
1, t
2, r
3, i
4, n 
5, g
```